# Excel VBA Loop Over ActiveX Textbox To Change BackColor If Condition Is Met

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, activex

I'm trying to loop through all the ActiveX Texboxes I have created on a sheet. My code has no errors, but it also does nothing. The first line activates the worksheet (name is specified on previous activated worksheet). As a note, I know almost nothing about VBA.

```
Worksheets(ws.Range("J2").Value).Activate
Dim OLEObj As OLEObject 

For Each OLEObj In Worksheets(ws.Range("J2").Value).OLEObjects
    If TypeName(OLEObj) = "TextBox" Then
        If OLEObj.Object.Value = "R" Then
            OLEObj.Object.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
    End If
Next OLEObj
```

The above code makes no change, but if I call out a textbox specifically, it does work:
Sheets(ws.Range("J2").Value).TextBox212.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: what happens when you use F8 to step through the code.

Comment: @freeflow Didn't even know I could do that. Looks like it just skips over the For loop.

Comment: what happens if you put a line before the loop:
`MsgBox Worksheets(ws.Range("J2").Value).OLEObjects.count`

Comment: That means 'Worksheets(ws.Range("J2").Value).OLEObjects' is returning an empty collection so the dext thing to do is a 'debug.print ws.Range("J2").Value to see what value is being passed to worksheets

Comment: @RedHare It's coming back as 0

Comment: @freeflow It's showing the worksheet name, as intended

Comment: If it is returning 0 then there are no Oleobjects on the sheet. Are you sure that you used ActiveX Textbox?

Comment: @RedHare Just figured it out! They are ActiveX Textboxes, but I had grouped them together. I didn't know that grouping them would cause them to not be considered OLEObjects anymore. I ungrouped and now it works. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

`If TypeName(OLEObj) = "TextBox" Then`

use

`If TypeName(OLEObj.Object) = "TextBox" Then`

`Typename(OLEObj)` will always be "OLEObject"

EDIT: adding full code -

```vb
Sub test()
 
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsTxtBoxes As Worksheet
    Dim oleObj As Object, wsName As String, obj As Object
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'for example: use a specific workbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("settings") 'for example
    wsName = ws.Range("J2").Value
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsTxtBoxes = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not wsTxtBoxes Is Nothing Then
        For Each oleObj In wsTxtBoxes.OLEObjects
            Set obj = oleObj.Object
            If TypeName(obj) = "TextBox" Then
                obj.BackColor = IIf(obj.Value = "R", RGB(255, 0, 0), vbWhite)
            End If
        Next oleObj
    Else
        'sheet not found...
        MsgBox "Worksheet '" & wsName & "' was not found in workbook '" & _
                wb.Name & "'", vbExclamation
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, it still isn't working. When implementing @RedHare's suggestion of MsgBox Worksheets(ws.Range("J2").Value).OLEObjects.count, I get 0. So, I think the biggest problem lies there.